# NginX wild card www.example.com/name

Tags: nginx, webserver

I have multiple websites on subdomains but instead of keeping them on a subdomain, I want to put them on something like [www.example.io/name](http://www.example.io/name) how do I do this in nginx?

I tried example.io/.* and this didn't work I got nginx 404 error

See my nginx server block below

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
   

    server_name xyz.example.io *.xyz.example.io  xyz.example.io/.* www.xyz.example.io;

    root /home/ubuntu/www/landing_frontend;
    index index.html index.php;



    location /scripts {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    index index.html index.php;
    }


location ~ \.php$ {



            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            fastcgi_index            index.php;
            include     fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            }

    }
```

Comment: Sorry I think the /name is what is confusing to you Richard. /name could be anything it could also be www.example.io/usa www.example.io/vehicles www.example.io/delivery so whatever the word is after the .io/* I want nginx to serve that page.

Comment: Another example of what I am talking about is this website below how do I configure nginx to make that /jamaica or /usa or /canada a part of the URL where the index.html file  https://www.caribbeanjobs.com/jamaica

https://www.caribbeanjobs.com/usa or https://www.caribbeanjobs.com/canada